# Webdriver FindElement by CssSelector Click Not Working

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a dropdown on a web page for selecting a country which has been rendered using the jQuery Chosen plugin. An extract of the html below,

```
<div>
<label for="phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry" id="phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_lblCountry" class="short required">Country*</label>:
    <div id="phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry_chzn" class="chzn-container undefined chzn-container-single" style="width: 199.44444px;">
       <a href="#x" class="chzn-single"><span>Please select ...</span><div><b></b></div></a>
       <div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 197.222px; top: 28px;">
          <div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" style="width: 162px;"></div>
          <ul class="chzn-results">
             <li id="phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected">Please select ...</li>
             <li id="phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry_chzn_o_1" class="active-result">United Kingdom</li>
             <li id="phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry_chzn_o_2" class="active-result">Afghanistan</li>
.......
```

If I use the Selenium IDE to record the actions to select the “United Kingdom” from the list the following script is recorded. Run snippet to see table with the commands in it.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Command</td>
    <td>Target</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.chzn-single > span</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry_chzn_o_1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can run this script repeatably in the IDE and the UK is selected from the dropdown each time. However, if I export the C#/Nunit/Webdriver code below

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.chzn-single > span")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry_chzn_o_1")).Click();
```

and execute it, it fails on  the 1st statement with the Selenium **Element Not Visible** exception.

Any advice on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This could be a timing issue. Try inserting a Thread.sleep(2000); between the statements. Note that the statement is in Java.

Answer (score 0):

you can try xPath and select like `//span[contains(.,'Please Select')]`

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait to make sure the dropdown is visible before the click

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement dropdown = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("a.chzn-single > span")));
dropdown.Click(); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry_chzn_o_1")).Click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately still not working, I don’t think this is a timing/visible issue. If I look at the properties of the **dropdown** variable I see the following. It is identified as a ((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)(dropdown)). Tagname: span, Text: “Please select ...” – which indicates to me the right element has been found. But the dropdown.Click() still fails. Could the use of the jQuery Chosen plugin be an issue in terms as how it works?

Comment: I've just rechecked the code you provided and realised I'd made a mistake. Now corrected all works. Many thanks.